# How to fix the Routes not found error in server error in swagger-blocks gem, even thought the routes exists in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger-blocks gem for API documentation. And when I try to test the API from the swagger UI it is giving me a response with status **404**, and in the server it is saying.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/api/v1/vendors"):
```

also the output of **rake routes | grep vendors**

```
api_v1_vendors POST   /api/v1/vendors(.:format)
```

The swagger UI is giving me the curl command.

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/vendors" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"w_flow_id\": \"112268_1\", \"service_type\": { \"translation\": [], \"editing\": [], \"lqa_proofreading\": [] }, \"vendors\": [ { \"email\": \"admin@example.com\", \"first_name\": \"admin\", \"last_name\": \"admin\" } ]}"
```

which on running on the terminal is giving me the response

```
{"error":"Invalid authentication.","status":401}
```

which was the expected output in swagger UI.

In **/api/v1/vendors_controller.rb** I have define the swagger path like

```
  swagger_path '/vendor_corrals' do
    operation :post do
      key :summary, 'Add vendor to the corral'
      key :description, 'Post the vendor with given params to vendor corral for particular workflow'
      # key :consumes, ['application/json']
      key :produces, ['application/json']
      key :tags, ['Vendor Corral']

      security 'Authentication-Token': []

      parameter name: :body, in: :body, required: true do
        schema type: :object do
          property :w_flow_id, type: :string, example: '112268_1'
          property :service_type, type: :object do
            property :translation, type: :array, example: [] do
              items type: :string
            end
            property :editing, type: :array, example: [] do
              items type: :string
            end
            property :lqa_proofreading, type: :array, example: [] do
              items type: :string
            end
          end
          property :vendors, type: :array do
            items type: :object do
              property :email, type: :string, example: 'admin@example.com'
              property :first_name, type: :string, example: 'admin'
              property :last_name, type: :string, example: 'admin'
            end
          end
        end
      end

      response 200 do
        key :description, 'Vendor Corral Response'
      end

      response 401 do
        key :description, 'Not Authorized'
      end

      response 422 do
        key :description, 'Unprocessable Entry'
      end

      response 500 do
        key :description, 'Internal Server Error'
      end
    end
  end
```

In **apidocs_controller.rb** I have

```
class ApidocsController < ApplicationController
  include Swagger::Blocks
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]

  swagger_root do
    key :swagger, '2.0'
    info do
      key :version, 'v1'
      key :title, 'R3 API Documentation'
    end

    key :host, 'localhost:3000'
    key :basePath, '/api/v1'
    key :schemes, [ 'http', 'https' ]
    key :consumes, ['application/json']
    key :produces, ['application/json']

    security_definition :'Authentication-Token', type: :apiKey do
      key :name, :'Authentication-Token'
      key :in, :header
    end
  end

  SWAGGERED_CLASSES = [
    Api::V1::VendorsController,
    self
  ].freeze

  def index
    render json: Swagger::Blocks.build_root_json(SWAGGERED_CLASSES)
  end
end
```

Can anyone explain to me, why I am getting this behavior from swagger-blocks and what is the best practice to follow while using swagger-blocks gem?